# Should I discuss salary increase with boss before meeting or during?

Tags: salary, raise, salary-review

**The bit that has me thinking**:
I'm a senior software developer with 17 years experience, with 2 years in my role in a FinTech startup. A couple of months ago I was having a casual chat with our COO about employee performance (in general, not my performance) and how he'd be prepared to pay XYZ for the right person who could demonstrate the je ne sais quoi of intellect and performance who could bring a certain *fire* to the role.

**The reason I'm thinking it**:
We've all recently received notice that in a few weeks we'll be discussing salary reviews with him & the CEO.

I expect I'll go into the meeting, sit for a bit of chit-chat, they'll show me the offer ABC and I'll be very polite and thankful to both of them.

But given what he's told me before, I don't want that to be the end of the conversation. I want to say something along the lines of "what could I guarantee for you today in terms of additional fire if you were to agree to double that offer?". I want him to give me some of that XYZ!

**My question is**:
Is this a terrible idea? Should I say this during the meeting (where it's easy for him to say "sorry, the decisions are already made"), or should I write up an email beforehand referencing our earlier conversation and put the "what could I guarantee" line to him there? That gives him time to think about it, but it also gives him the opportunity to say "this is the doubled figure: ABC" when it's not actually doubled and I just don't know any better.

Comment: Normally, you should discuss salary raise during the meeting. That is what the meeting is for. If you try to talk to the boss about the salary raise before the meeting and he is too busy with other tasks, he may feel you are trying to pressure him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something to discuss one-on-one with your boss. And usually in the form of "Hey, what would you need to see from me to justify a raise -- or to help you justify it to upper management?"

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are wanting a significantly increased offer (you said Doubled) but conditional on certain performance factors, then I would suggest emailing him ahead of time.

Reference the convo and the fact that you know these talks are due to happen soon:

"Hi COO,

I feel I'm ready to take on the extra challenge of *role expectations*, with a view to *Salary XYZ* that you referenced the other day. I'd like to prove that I have *certain fire* needed between now and when we have our Salary review so that I can prove to you and the business that I'm the person that will take this company to that next level.

What can I do in terms of *deliverables goals or other Metrics* to demonstrate this?"

Or something like that.

You are asking for a Gauntlet to be thrown down - for them to give you a herculean task "Double our sales revenue" or "make our app run on Quantum computing" (you get the idea) - and then you to smash it out between now and then to give them the business justification for that significantly higher salary band.

Of course, the flipside is if they issue a challenge and you don't succeed, you may not get any salary increase - but if you think you have what it takes - go for gold!